# Riffling Cards in Mathematica

Tags: algorithm, wolfram-mathematica

My friend posed this question to me; felt like sharing it here.

Given a deck of cards, we split it into 2 groups, and "interleave them"; let us call this operation a 'split-join'. And repeat the same operation on the resulting deck.

*E.g.*, **{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }** becomes **{ 1, 2 }** & **{ 3, 4 }** *(split)* and we get **{ 1, 3, 2, 4 }** *(join)*

Also, if we have an odd number of cards i.e., **{ 1, 2, 3 }** we can split it like **{ 1, 2 }** & **{ 3 }** (bigger-half first) leading to **{ 1, 3, 2 }**
(i.e., `n` is split up as `Ceil[n/2]` & `n-Ceil[n/2]`)

The question my friend asked me was:

> HOW many **such** split-joins are needed to get the original deck back?

And that got me wondering:

If the deck has *n* cards, what is the number of split-joins needed if:

- *n* is even ?
- *n* is odd  ?
- *n* is a power of '2' ? [I found that we then need *log (n)* (base 2) number of split-joins...]
- (Feel free to explore different scenarios like that.)

Is there a simple pattern/formula/concept correlating *n* and the number of split-joins required?

I believe, this is a good thing to explore in Mathematica, especially, since it provides the `Riffle[]` method.

Comment: How do your split your deck when there is an odd number of items?

Comment: Please write proper English and don't litter your questions with unusual contractions, emoticons and converting all your "and"s to ampersands. We expect a professional tone here.

Comment: @Benoit -- Have added 1 strategy in the question, but feel free to assume the opposite too, if you can find more interesting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old question I know, but strange no one put up an actual mathematica solution..

```
 countrifflecards[deck_] := Module[{n = Length@deck, ct, rifdeck},
      ct = 0;
      rifdeck = 
        Riffle @@ 
          Partition[ # , Ceiling[ n/2], Ceiling[ n/2], {1, 1}, {} ] &;
      NestWhile[(++ct; rifdeck[#]) &, deck, #2 != deck &,2 ]; ct]
```

This handles even and odd cases:

```
 countrifflecards[RandomSample[ Range[#], #]] & /@ Range[2, 52, 2]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 12, 4, 8, 18, 6, 11, 20, 18, 28, 5, 10, 12, 36, 
>   12, 20, 14, 12, 23, 21, 8}

```
 countrifflecards[RandomSample[ Range[#], #]] & /@ Range[3, 53, 2]
```

> {2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 12, 4, 8, 18, 6, 11, 20, 18, 28, 5, 10, 12, 36, 12, 
>   20, 14, 12, 23, 21, 8, 52}

You can readily show if you add a card to the odd-case the extra card will stay on the bottom and not change the sequence, hence the odd case result is just the `n+1` even result..

```
 ListPlot[{#, countrifflecards[RandomSample[ Range[#], #]]} & /@ 
      Range[2, 1000]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

To quote [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Out-Shuffle.html):

> The numbers of out-shuffles needed to return a deck of n=2, 4, ... to its original order are 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 12, 4, 8, 18, 6, 11, ... (Sloane's A002326), which is simply the multiplicative order of 2 (mod n-1). For example, a deck of 52 cards therefore is returned to its original state after eight out-shuffles, since 2**8=1 (mod 51) (Golomb 1961). The smallest numbers of cards 2n  that require 1, 2, 3, ... out-shuffles to return to the deck's original state are 1, 2, 4, 3, 16, 5, 64, 9, 37, 6, ... (Sloane's A114894).

The case when `n` is odd isn't addressed.

Note that the article also includes a [Mathematica notebook](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Games/Out-Shuffle.nb) with functions to explore out-shuffles.

Comment: thanks a lot for these pointers. 
Will explore for different cases and see if i find something interesting.

Answer (score 5):

If we have an odd number of cards `n==2m-1`, and if we split the cards such that during each shuffle the first group contains `m` cards, the second group `m-1` cards, and the groups are joined such that no two cards of the same group end up next to each other, then the number of shuffles needed is equal to `MultiplicativeOrder[2, n]`.

To show this, we note that after one shuffle the card which was at position `k` has moved to position `2k` for `0<=k<m` and to `2k-2m+1` for `m<=k<2m-1`, where `k` is such that `0<=k<2m-1`. Written modulo `n==2m-1` this means that the new position is `Mod[2k, n]` for all `0<=k<n`. Therefore, for each card to return to its original position we need `N` shuffles where `N` is such that `Mod[2^N k, n]==Mod[k, n]` for all `0<=k<n` from which is follows that `N` is any multiple of `MultiplicativeOrder[2, n]`.

Note that due to symmetry the result would have been exactly the same if we had split the deck the other way around, i.e. the first group always contains `m-1` cards and the second group `m` cards. I don't know what would happen if you alternate, i.e. for odd shuffles the first group contains `m` cards, and for even shuffles `m-1` cards.

Comment: that's beautiful (symmetry, I did feel it should not make a difference, but sometimes intuition can go wrong!)...have some other special cases in my mind...let me see...! Thanks a lot indeed...

Answer (score 4):

There's old work by magician/mathematician Persi Diaconnis about restoring the order with perfect riffle shuffles. Ian Stewart wrote about that work in one of his 1998 Scientific American Mathematical Recreation columns -- see, e.g.: http://www.whydomath.org/Reading_Room_Material/ian_stewart/shuffle/shuffle.html